# Bot Framework - Intercept outgoing messages and alter them

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

I would like to alter outgoing messages using an interceptor. I already have an  [activity logger in place](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-middleware), but unfortunately it is not suited to alter messages before the are sent to the user.
Let's say I populate the id field on the activity inside the LogAsync method, the id will not be sent to the connector.

Is there another way to intercept messages?

Comment: Why you want to alter the message? Why you want to change the activity id (which it makes sense it cannot be changed)

Comment: Since the id field is optional and not read only, I wanted ensure that there is always an id I can use throughout the flow (including activity logger)  and use it as kind of reference.